# Alternative for Counter Strike

Tags: 17.04, games, alternative

I used to play Counter-Strike but switched to Ubuntu 17.04 and no longer have CS. I tried to install it using Wine but it didn't work properly, so I would like to find free alternatives.

The game should have different maps to play in as well as different game modes. It will have to be first-person, like the original game.
The graphics need to be ok, but not to bad.
There should be different kinds of guns, like snipers, rifles, shotguns and ETC.

Comment: Have you tried super tux kart?

Comment: @dsstorefile I have no updates for BionicBeaver (Otherwise known as 18.04), and i do not know how to update

Comment: @stedotmartin, no, and it doesn't fit my description as it is not anything like CS

Comment: What do you mean with "no longer have CS"? According to [steam page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/10/CounterStrike/) it is available on linux...

Comment: I cannot get Steam to work for me

Comment: So I decided that getting a alternative?!

Comment: if you are running 18.04 LTS; you should edit your question (& tag) and change 17.04 (2017 April release of Ubuntu which is now EOL) to be 18.04 LTS.  17.04 is *off-topic* here due EOL status, unless you are having trouble upgrading to a supported release  (your reply to dsstorefile states 18.04)

Comment: I'm running on 17.04

Comment: Possible **off-topic** question, as 17.04 is EOL (2017.April+9months = 2018-Jan-13).  If you want a longer life than short-term-releases provide, use LTS or long-term-support releases of Ubuntu. (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Urban Terror ist a nice fps

Answer (score 0):

Counter strike is available for linux distributions through Steam.
Try installing steam and download it from there, in case you've already bought it. A helpful link to install steam, could be worth checking out (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-steam-start-gaming-linux/)

**List of requirements:**

[image]

Comment: Is it free? If so I am having trouble installing Steam?

Comment: Counter strike has never been free - https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/ - CS:GO, CS:SO and CS are all paid games.

Comment: I know that but i'd like to have a free alternative?

Comment: A free alternative, some game that could be like CS would be either fortnite or Playerunknowns battlegrounds. Those are the few I know about. Other than that, this is not a linux-related question and you should try google and do some research on your issue. EDIT: Not sure whether those games work on linux. Sorry.

Comment: I have Fortnite on PS4 and Fortnite is only for Windows or Mac, I haven't tried Playerunknowns BatlleGround. Thanks Anyways